# How did I get two remotes with the same url (one with fetch and one push)

Tags: git, repository

I've been trying to learn more about git recently. I wanted to know what a remote is and I found answers to that, simple enough, then I ran `git remote -v` and there are two with identical urls but one is followed by (fetch) and the other (pull). So

```
origin http://someurl_git/application (fetch)
origin http://someurl_git/application (push)
```

I'm simply wondering how it got in that state? From what I read in another thread it's not normal to have two identical urls. I'd like to try and trace back and figure out how it got that way. And what issues this could cause.

Then I ran:

```
git remote show origin
```

And it listed this:

```
* remote origin 
Fetch: origin http://someurl_git/application
Push: origin http://someurl_git/application 
HEAD branch: master
Remote branches: 
  BranchA tracked
  develop tracked
  BranchB tracked
Local branches configured for 'git pull': 
    develop merges with remote develop
    master  merges with remote master
Local refs configured for 'git push':
    develop pushes to develop (local out of date)
    master  pushes to master  (up to date)
```

My questions are:

1. Why is there a Fetch and a Push above with the same url?
2. What is the correlation between 'refs' and 'branches'?  Does ref just mean the remote branch that my push will affect? Whereas branch in the local context just means... 'the local branch a pull will affect'  ?
3. And what does " (local out of date)" and ("up to date") mean? Does that just mean any changes in my local repo that are not reflected in the remote repo? But why does it say "up to date" for pushes to master? I would think it'd say the same "remote/local out of date" also.

I feel like I'm missing some terminology but if that's all that's ok, I just want to avoid any issues as more developers are involved now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*1. Why is there a Fetch and a Push above with the same url?*

Because in some settings one could need to pull from one source but push to another. If it's not the case (by default) then both feature the same url. That's indeed normal.

---

*2.a What is the correlation between 'refs' and 'branches'? Does ref just mean the remote branch that my push will affect? Whereas branch in the local context just means... 'the local branch a pull will affect' ?*

Refs are pointers to commits. There are two types of refs : branches and tags.

---

*3. And what does " (local out of date)" and ("up to date") mean? Does that just mean any changes in my local repo that are not reflected in the remote repo? But why does it say "up to date" for pushes to master? I would think it'd say the same "remote/local out of date" also.*

"(local out of date)" means that the remote branch has new commits still unknown to your local branch, whereas "(up to date)" means both point at the same commit.

Answer (score 1):

[Romain Valeri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71249032/1256452) covers your three questions directly, but it sounds like you need some more background information.

> ... I wanted to know what a remote is ...

I like to say that it's mainly a short name for a URL.  That glosses over a lot of details, though.  It *is* a name—how long is up to you; make it short so that it's easy to type—and it should store at least one URL.  It can store two URLs quite easily, though: one is the "fetch" URL, and the other is the "push" URL.  You set these with `git remote set-url` or using `git config`.  Each remote's URL is stored under a unique key.  If the remote is named `origin`—as the first one normally is—this key is:

```
remote.origin.url
```

for the fetch URL, and:

```
remote.origin.pushurl
```

for the push URL.  If the push URL is not set—if there is no `remote.origin.pushurl` key—the push URL is automatically the *same as* the fetch URL.

Configuration keys go in files like `.git/config` and `$HOME/.gitconfig` or `$HOME/.config/git` or similar (the precise location of configuration files is system-dependent).  They have this dot-separated form when we use the `git config` command to query or set them, and for most other uses, but inside the configuration files, they are stored in a modified [INI file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).  The modified format that Git uses shows up like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

for instance.  This pair of entries under the `[remote "origin"]` section header defines `remote.origin.url` and `remote.origin.fetch`.

#### More about config files

Some key-value pairs in Git are *single-valued*.  For instance, the `user.name` and `user.email` settings work this way.  When you run `git commit` to make a *new commit*, Git runs the internal equivalent of `git config --get user.name` to get your name.

Suppose your *global* configuration file says:

```
[user]
    name = Fred Flintstone
    email = fred@rockville.prehistory
```

but your *local* (in-Git-repository) `.git/config` file says:

```
[user]
    name = Barney Rubble
```

(with no setting for `user.email`).  The result of running:

```
git config --get user.name
```

will be `Barney Rubble`, because the local setting, which *is* set here, overrides the global setting.  The result of running:

```
git config --get user.email
```

will be `fred@rockville.prehistory` because there's no local setting, so the *global* setting is the only one available.

Other key-value pairs can be *multi-valued*.  In this case, *each setting* is visible, but the Git program that's using these settings must run the internal equivalent of `git config --get-all` rather htan `git config --get`.  With the above configuration files, running:

```
git config --get-all user.name
```

would spill out two lines:

```
Fred Flintstone
Barney Rubble
```

Without looking at each individual program, there is no way to know whether it will use `git config --get` or `git config --get-all` (or the internal equivalents).  So you never know, if you set a configuration item more than once, which commands might use *all* the settings, and which ones will use only the *last* setting, unless they tell you in their documentation.  Sometimes you can find out by experiment.  You also cannot tell, without documentation, what settings might be *used* now or in the future.  For instance, you can run:

```
git config --global french.city paris
```

right now.  *Nothing in Git uses this setting today* so the fact that you've added:

```
[french]
    city = paris
```

to your global Git configuration *affects no Git program today*.  Should some Git program start using that setting next year, however, well, you've set it, so it will do whatever that program means for it to do in 2023.

The fact that these settings are free-form makes it ridiculously easy to introduce typos and never know you have done so.  Always check settings carefully!

#### The `git remote` program

The `git remote` program is, like a lot of Git commands, rather complicated.  It started out simple, but it grew over time.  It can:

- show, add, rename, or delete some remote;
- show or set the URL(s) for a remote;
- show or set the `fetch` line(s) for a remote, which are multi-valued;
- run `git fetch` to a single remote or multiple remotes;
- "prune" a remote (this is similar to `git fetch -p` but slightly different);
- set or delete the "head" of any given remote; or
- "show" information about a particular remote.

Most of these operations *do not* call up the remote in question, i.e., they don't reach out over the network to tickle another set of Git software to look at some other Git repository.  The exceptions to this rule are:

- `update` (fetch), which has to call up the remote to find new commits or other new objects that may exist there;
- `prune`, which is kind of like fetching;
- `set-head` with the `--auto` option; and
- `show`.

The last one—`git remote show`—*optionally* calls up the remote.  The default is that it should do so, if given the name of a remote; the `-n` flag prevents this.

By calling up the remote—which `git ls-remote` does as well; try it sometime; note that it may produce a lot of output and you might want to pipe it through a pager—the `git show` command can find out which branch names exist *on* the remote.  This helps it figure out what `git fetch` or `git push` would do, if you ran `git fetch` or `git push` right now.

When used with `-n`, the `git show` command can't actually achieve that.  This changes the output somewhat since it (`git remote show`) knows that it (`git remote show`) doesn't know what it (`git fetch` or `git push`) would do if run with that remote name.

#### Atomicity

There is, however, something I consider a fairly big problem with `git remote show` *without* `-n`.  Suppose you have cloned a highly active repository (such as the Git repository for Git or for the Linux kernel).  You're curious what `git fetch origin` might bring over, if you run it now, so you run:

```
git remote show origin
```

Your Git calls up another Git over at GitHub or `kernel.org` or wherever, has a fairly long conversation with that other software, and eventually spills out some statistics.  This takes *many seconds*, and then you read through those same statistics also for many seconds—or maybe you come back after a lunch break to read them, or something.

You then decide *ah, I want _____* (fill in some blank here), so you run `git fetch origin ______` ... and you get something *very different* from what `git show` showed you because in that long delay between the time you *looked to see what you would get*, and the time you actually ran `git fetch` to *get* things, *everything changed*.

This doesn't mean that the act of looking first is necessarily *bad*.  It works fine for highly-inactive repositories, for instance.  It's just not guaranteed to reflect the future reality.  If you want to know what *will* happen, you have to do the thing—whatever it is—and then see what *did* happen.  In the case of Git, that means running `git fetch`.

This sort of thing is one of many reasons I dislike `git pull`.  With `git pull`, you run `git fetch` and then **without looking to see what *did* happen** you make the assumption that something you expected to happen did happen, and you run a second Git command, `git merge` or `git rebase`.  That second command works with what *did* happen.  It does not work with what you *expected* unless you got lucky and got exactly what you expected.

If you know a lot about the repository from which you're going to fetch-and-<second-command>, that's reasonable enough.  But if you don't know that much, instead of using `git show` and then `git pull`, I personally prefer to run `git fetch`, then *see what I got*, and only *then* run a second command (or not).  But this does vary, case-by-case, from one Git repository to another (and also based on how long it's been since I poked around with it).

The general idea here is *atomicity*.  Some operations, like `git fetch` or `git push`, are "atomic": they cannot be broken into sub-operations, at least not without radically changing things.  Other operations, like `git pull`, *can*.  Using `git remote show remote` is, in effect, an attempt to go below the level of atomicity actually offered by Git.  So I avoid that, and just run `git fetch`, which is the level at which Git really is atomic.  (See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)

Comment: Okay, respectfully stepping aside. Damn, I have been torek'd again! (Just kidding, great answer of course ;-)